# krakenjs/makara i18n and content from external api (contentful)

Tags: node.js, kraken.js, contentful

I want to build a blog with krakenjs and want to use the i18n feature from it (makara): https://github.com/krakenjs/makara

Makara requires to put all locales into static files. eg. locales/US/en/

How can I use it with dynamic content from e.g. contentful.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the excerpt from the makara readme that explains how to do this:

> If you have runtime values to be inserted, use dust brace to select the value from the dust template context as in the index.greeting line. Note that there is no restriction on inserting HTML tags into the messages. They are just another string of characters as far as the content processing is concerned.

So you would have a property like so:

```
index.dynamic={dynamicConent}
```

The value of `dynamicContent` will be picked up at run-time from the dust template context.